# jquery ajax setinterval issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function refreshbids() {
        var element = $("#biddingdiv");
        element.load("bids.php?id=<? echo $uid; ?>&init=1&auctionid=<? echo $auctionid; ?>&"+(new Date()).getTime());
    }


    refreshbids();

    setInterval(refreshbids, 5000);


});
```

When we leave that page and return to it, it seems that the bids.php gets loaded faster, ie the interval cache is not cleared.
we tried window.clearInterval(refreshbids); but it didnt work. Please help.

Should we clear interval at the beginning of the load or check if it's not clear and clear it then?

thanks

Comment: _it seems that the bids.php gets loaded faster_ ?

Comment: what does your `.load`-function do ? on default  https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ you pass an callback which is handled when the element is loaded or am I missing something ?

Comment: Xzen - it loads bids.php into #biddingdiv, that should be clear

Comment: user2181397 - not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It depends altogether on what you want to do!  In the code that you show, `refreshbids()` is first (*always ...)* called once, then it is set to be called every 5 seconds thereafter.   This not-timed first call is most likely why you say that it is “loaded faster” when you “return to” the page:   the function will be called immediately at that time.   Calls to `clearInterval()` would be irrelevant in this case:   the function isn’t being called (the first time ...) by any sort of timer.

*FYI:*   Because the state of things immediately after page-load can be “a little dicey, and browser-specific,” you might wish to use a `setTimeout()` call in the page-ready routine to fire the call to `refreshbids()` in, say, 100 milliseconds.   This one-shot subroutine could then `setInterval` to cause subsequent repeated calls to occur.  (And, no, you would never `clearInterval`...) That “human not-noticeable fraction of a second” moves the start of the timed activity very slightly later-in-time from actually happening *at* page-ready, and this can avoid a lot of timing problems.

Comment: Hi Mike. What we need is to load bids.php in #biddingdiv once at page load, then refresh it every 5 seconds. Now the MAIN problem that we have is that when we reload a container div that holds #biddingdiv in it, the #biddingdiv goes nuts and loads the page bids.php all the time and it loads the bids.php from previous viewed pages. As if some log is not cleared right.

Comment: Basically, each container div that we visit, it keeps track on all previously viewed biddingdiv's... we tried using clearInterval but without any success.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"goes nuts."* Use the browser debugger to **see** what is being requested and returned. Consider logging the actual string that you're passing to `element.load()`. Add a log-comment each time the interval goes off. Once you are able to **see** a bug like this, it's usually easy to find-and-fix it. Until then, you're shooting in the dark.

Comment: I was using a debugger and reported what I got. Simply, setinterval doesn't get cleared since it is in ajax window and every new refresh of that window triggers a new setinterval, which leads to much faster refreshes etc. Apparently since that container div is loaded via ajax, it never clears the interval, and they just are added to the queue on each refresh of the container.

Comment: I don't see `setInterval` being called "in an Ajax window," but, come to think of it, maybe the definition of `function refreshbids()` ought not be *inside* the `ready` handler? Unlike `setTimeout`, which *can* accumulate, I was under the impression that `setInterval` manipulated one and only one timer. Oh, well.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I managed to fix that with this on top of $(document).ready(function() {:

```
for(i=0; i<9999; i++)
{
    window.clearInterval(i);
}
```

Now i am not sure what are the values for setinterval and how effective this is in the term of script quickness, so if you have any fixes / better ideas, let me know.